# PHP Phalcon как перенаправить пользователя после регистрации?

Tags: php, phalcon

Хочу перенаправить пользователя после регистрации на его страницу, то есть в адресной строке должно получится http://localhost/users/show/Sergey, происходит перенаправление на страницу пользователя, но в адресной строке остаётся - http://localhost/users/register.

```
<code>
    $router->add(
        "/users/show/{name}",
        [
            "controller" => "users",
            "action" => "show",
        ]
    );
</code>
```

Это роутер.

```
<code>
    public function registerAction()
        {
            $user = new Users();

            // Store and check for errors
            $success = $user->save(
                $this->request->getPost(),
                [
                    "name",
                    "email",
                ]

            );


            if ($success) {
                $this->flash->success("Вы зарегистрированы");
                return $this->dispatcher->forward(
                    [
                        "controller" => "users",
                        "action" => "show",
                        "params" => [$user->name]

                    ]
               );

           } else {
                echo "Произошли следующие проблемы: ";

                $messages = $user->getMessages();

                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    echo $message->getMessage(), "<br/>";
                }

           }


        }
</code>
```

Это контролер. Подскажите где совершаю ошибку?

Comment: $this->response->redirect("controller/action")
диспатчер только вызывает другой контроллер/экшн для действий(например, проверка логина или доступ), если нужна переадресация используйте redirect

Comment: Ааа, ну хорошо, как мне определить правильно "for", чем он является:     <code>                                                                                                               [
                    "for" => "",
                    "controller" => "users",
                    "action" => "show",
                    "params" => [$user->name]

                ]                                                                                                        </code>

Comment: где какой for?https://docs.phalconphp.com/ru/latest/reference/dispatching.html написано что переадресация на действие, а не страницу

Comment: Как определить for при редиректе? Выше я написал пример кода, чем за что отвечает for?

Comment: return $this->response->redirect("users/show/$user->name"); А вот так делать можно ? Это считается нормально ?

Comment: Не совсем, можете через url https://docs.phalconphp.com/ru/latest/reference/url.html и потом это передавать в редирект

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так: 
use Phalcon\Http\Response;

```
    $response = new Response();
    $response->redirect("/users/show/".$user->username);
    $response->send();
```